# Mongoose timestamp gives inacurate results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

CreatedAt gives the time 3 hours ago. How can i make it display the current time?

The schema:

```
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    text: String,
    link: String,
    description: String,
    imgLink: String,
    source: String,
} , { timestamps: true }
);

articleSchema.index({ createdAt: 1,  expires: '60m', default: Date.now });

var Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

export default Article;
```

Comment: 'three hours ago' sounds like you may be somewhat East of the Greenwich Meridien. Are you getting universal not local time?

Comment: Yes i am getting universal time, not local

Answer (score 0):

You probably getting different time zone from mongoose.

Try installing `npm i moment-timezone`

And change your Date to the right timezone, here is the docs for that: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/